# Split a range of numbers in equal parts in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with 40 lac rows with a column 'playcount' which has min value 1 and max value of around 17,000.

I would like to split this table into 15 groups by adding a column which will have values 1 to 15 based on 'playcount' column.

Hive has a function NTILE which allows to do something similar. Here if I did `NTILE(15) OVER (ORDER BY playcount) AS mygroup`, it does break it up but based on count of playcount values and as the lower values are lot lot more( more than 50% have values less than 5), the grouping is such that values over 35 have group value of 15(maximum).

I would like to do the grouping based on the playcount and not on count of playcount values.

Is something similar possible in hive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I can think of is `playcount%15 as mygroup`.